# How to randomly generate a list of function calls from a list of args and a list of functions?

Tags: programming

I want to generate a list of simple trigonometric questions in `TeXForm`, for example, as follows.

```
Evaluate the following expressions.
\begin{enumerate}
\item $\sin 30^\circ$
\item $\sec 90^\circ$
% ... others go here ...
\item $\csc 315^\circ$
\end{enumerate}
```

So I can just copy and paste it to my LaTeX input file to create a problem sheet.

I have a list of arguments `args` and a list of functions `funcs` as follows.

```
args = Array[15 # &, 24, 0];
funcs = {Sin, Cos, Tan, Csc, Sec, Cot};
```

How to define a function `GenerateProblem[n_]` where `n` represents the number of problems to generate in `TeXForm`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Roughly

```
args=Array[15 #&,24,0];
funcs={Sin,Cos,Tan,Csc,Sec,Cot};

generateProblem=Column[StringRiffle/@RandomSample[Tuples@{funcs,args},#]]&

TeXForm@generateProblem@4
```

> \begin{array}{l}
>  \text{Tan 180} \\
>  \text{Sin 210} \\
>  \text{Sec 210} \\
>  \text{Tan 300} \\
> \end{array}

**Edit 1.** This produces TeX math expressions like \sin , \sec  etc

```
generateProblem = Column[#1@#2 & @@@ RandomSample[Tuples@{funcs, args}, #]] &

TeXForm@generateProblem@4
```

> \begin{array}{l}
>  \sec (60) \\
>  \sec (255) \\
>  \csc (195) \\
>  \sin (30) \\
> \end{array}